# Filtering incoming Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I have a **Sentence** model that will contain a single sentence in the body column.  It is important to have only one sentence per row.  However, users may enter more than one sentence in the form.  Not a problem.  I actually want to encourage that.

So what I need to do is split the sentences and save only one sentence per row.  I am able to do this in the controller fairly easily (a simple .split(". ") will do it), however that becomes a bit unmaintainable after time.  I really feel like the model should handle this.

So what I am thinking is doing some sort of *before_save* hook in my Sentence model and doing the split in there.  Obviously that creates some problems of its own as well.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Are you sure splitting on `'.'` will be sufficient? Sentences can end with `'!'` and `'?'` also.

Comment: Yeah, I will have to split on multiple different marks.  But the main thing that I was dealing with was at which level do I split.  But thanks for pointing that out.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would refractor it into a class method, such as:

Semi-Pseudo Code:

```
class Sentence << ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.split_into_sentences(input)
    input.split(".")
  end

  def self.create_sentences_from_body(body)
    split_into_sentences(body).each{|s| Sentence.create(:body => s)}
  end

end
```

So you could call in your controller:

```
Sentence.create_sentences_from_body(params[:text])
```